# AngularJS SOAP Call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, soap

im new in this field of IT and i'm doing an apprentienship, the goal of this appreintienship, is making an app that retrieve data from a server that runs SOAP (unfortunately), that's my first call for gettin' some Info about Owner inside the server. The call doesn't work (i wrote sh*t in my code for sure) and i don't know how to correct it and make a better SOAP call. 
Here's the code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
    var sr = 
                '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' + 
                '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
                    '<soap:Header>' +
                        '<AuthHeader xmlns="Logisense_EngageIP">' + 
                            '<Username>admin</Username>' + 
                            '<Password>admin</Password>' +
                        '</AuthHeader>' +
                    '</soap:Header>' +
                    '<soap:Body>' + 
                        '<GetOwnersUsers xmlns="Logisense_EngageIP">' + 
                            '<ownerUsername>string</ownerUsername>' + 
                        '</GetOwnersUsers>' +
                    '</soap:Body>' +
                '</soap:Envelope>';
    var soapResponse = null;
    function makeSoap(){
        $http.post('31.44.16.67/GetOwnersUsers', sr)
            .success(function(data) {
                soapResponse = data;
                $scope.response = soapResponse;
            });
    }
    $scope.callSoap = function(){
        $scope.soapRequest = sr;
        makeSoap();
    };
});
```

Thanks you all anticipately for tips and hints!

Answer (score 1):

SOAP is the worst thing that can happen to a webapp.

For our apps we use the [javascript SOAP client library](https://github.com/gtathub/js-soap-client).

In your angular app you need to create a module with a factory:

```
angular.module('angularSoap', []).factory("$soap", [ '$q', "$http", function($q, $http) {
    return {
        post : function(action, params) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var soapParams = new SOAPClientParameters();
            for ( var param in params) {
                soapParams.add(param, params[param]);
            }
            var soapCallback = function(e) {
                if (e.constructor.toString().indexOf("function Error()") != -1) {
                    deferred.reject(e);
                } else {
                    deferred.resolve(e);
                }
            }
            SOAPClient.invoke('http://31.44.16.67/GetOwnersUsers', action, soapParams, true, soapCallback);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
} ]);
```

You need to inject `angularSoap` in your main app.

```
angular.module('yourApp', ['angularSoap']);
```

Then you will have access to a `$soap` service.

```
return $soap.post("ws:authentificationRequestParameter", {
    login : login,
    password : password,
    autoLog : autoLog
});
```

You can also try the [angular-soap](https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/angular-soap) plugin which didn't work for us in firefox. (fine in chrome).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so i need to write only this to perform a soap call? Or i need to add something else like the soap request i want to perform?

Comment: in the hours of work from my comment, i did this, and i got some error that are making me depressed and unable to keep up with this apprentienship. 
Here is the punlker of the code, can you help me to get out of this? https://plnkr.co/edit/ThP70IqhwhQumPd686Nw?p=info

Comment: EDIT:
Finally I can comunicate with the server, he deny all my request, but atleast I can comunicate (That's a big step forward). The problem now is that the server run SSL, so i need to authenticate myself. how i can do that? I used the angular-soap library you linked before. Here's the code revisited. https://plnkr.co/edit/ThP70IqhwhQumPd686Nw?p=info 
Thanks you for the help!

Comment: @Wallcraft looks like there's a $soap.setCredentials("username","password"); method. Not sure how you can make it secure though...

Comment: Okay, nevermind about my server with SSL, i found a public web server with some simple APIs. I tried to perform a SOAP call and in the console i get this errors  -> "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.ripedevelopment.com/webservices/LocalTime.asmx?wsdl. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access." and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null" 
Here's the code https://plnkr.co/edit/ymko1PvfGD8i5yWEztRU?p=catalogue

Comment: @Wallcraft I don't know. I tried with other public APIs and I get the same error. Maybe try to put your code on a server, not localhost. Other than that I don't know. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks the same, you did enought for me ahahah i will make another question for solve this problem, i think i have resolve it, but i'm not sure, i downloaded a plug in for chrome that allow CORS and i get a different errors. 
And i found some differences. First i got 500 error , and i can send another call to the serve, without plug in is like my call become "null" or semething else.